# combining find and $group in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to complete this query:

```
  db.cityinfo.find(
{$group: {_id: {state:"$state", city:"$city"}, 
total_pop: {$sum:"$pop"}}})
```

However, I get the error "unknown top level operator: $group". Is it because I'm trying to use $group function inside the find function and that isn't allowed? Im trying to combine the population based on city and states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use an [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), not a standard query.

As such, the syntax would be:

```
 db.cityinfo.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: {state:"$state", city:"$city"}, 
total_pop: {$sum:"$pop"}}}])
```

Comment: so it is not possible to add an aggregate pipeline into a standard query?

Comment: Aggregation pipelines are a different concept. They allow resulting documents to be transformed through [pipeline stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operator-reference), whereas a standard query only support field level omission through [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).